# Express POST - Returned JSON is treated as invalid by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, express

I am trying to write a small authentication service using Express and Node.

I did a search on SO and don't seem to find my answer, even though there're many similar questions.

I tried many variations of my server side code but it seems I am still missing something.

The POST call is made from an HTML page with some jQuery code (ajax call).

I enter the post() method in Express but when it returns response to the HTML page, always the ajax error handler is executed, never the success handler.

My JSON which I return seems valid to me. I tried calling send and json on the response object but nothing really works.

What am I missing?

```
var mod = require('express');

var auth = require('./login_module.js'); // my module

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/login', function(request, response) {
   
   console.log("post method called");
   
   var credentials = request.body;
   console.log("credentials = " + credentials);
   console.log(credentials);
   
   auth.authenticate(credentials.username, credentials.password, function(result){
        console.log("Authentication Result: " + result);
        var code = result === 1 ? 200 : 401;
        console.log("Response Code: " + code);
        var res = {
            data : "Response Code: " + code
        };
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
        
        // So far I am good!

        response.statusCode = code;
        response.json(res);
        
        // Response is now sent
        // but not recognized as 
        // valid JSON in the client.
        console.log("response sent");
   });
   
});

app.listen(10101);
```

jQuery call:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#btn" ).click(function(){
                  alert('calling now!');
                  var obj = {
                    username: $('#usrn').val(),
                    password: $('#pwd').val()
                  };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'http://localhost:10101/login',
                    data: obj,
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        alert('got response back!');
                        if ("200" === textStatus){
                            $('#status').text('Login succeeded!');
                        }else if ("401" === textStatus){
                            $('#status').text('Login failed!');
                        }else{
                            $('#status').text('Invalid status received: ' + textStatus);
                        }
                    },
                    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        alert("Error when getting response.");
                    },
                    
                    dataType: 'json'
                });
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Replace `response.json(res);` with `response.send(JSON.stringify(res));` and you're golden

Comment: No luck. Still error handler called in the browser (I am testing with FF). I think I tried that already (tried 4-5 different variations already as mentioned).

Comment: And what does the error say

Comment: Could you paste your jquery call ?

Comment: console.log the arguments to the error function and tell us what the error is. Invalid JSON would normally be a parse error

Comment: textStatus = "error", errorThrown = "" (I see it in the debugger). This doesn't seem too useful (to me at least). And jqXHR has readyState = 0, status = 0, statusText = "error". Hm, I guess you're saying it's maybe not an invalid JSON but something else.

Comment: That means it's not a parse error, so invalid JSON is not the issue. Did you try using just `/login` as an url for the ajax call,

Comment: And the console.logs on the serverside shows up everytime you click the button ?

Comment: How would it know the host and the port then?!

Comment: I'm assuming your page is running on the same host and port, and that's what it will use as default.

Comment: "And the console.logs on the serverside shows up everytime you click the button" Not sure what you mean. The error handler alert shows up.

Comment: Oh, no. It is running at file:///C:/some_path/login.html. (I just double click on this HTML file from the Windows Explorer).

Comment: Ajax from a file protocol doesn't work very well, and now you're probably violating the same origin policy as well. You need a webserver. Also, you have several console.logs in the node.js script, and everytime you click the button those should log to STDOUT and show in the node.js window.

Comment: If you see them popping up as you click the button, the request reached the server, and that part is at least working, so then it's probably something you're doing wrong when returning the data, or the same origin policy kicking in, as protocols, domains and ports must match.

Comment: Oh same origin policy. That could be it. Yes, these show server-side logs do show up, I have a comment in my code "So far I am good!". Yes, it does make a round trip (client-server-client). I thought you were talking about the browser-side. So I see now. OK, I will try it from some web server tomorrow. Thanks a lot for the help! Hope it behaves better from a web server.

Comment: well just make your express app render the login page on /login

Comment: if you absolutely want your auth service and your login page to be on two different urls, you have to add CORS headers to your responses :
`app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
      next();
})`

Comment: when you run the node server from your terminal/command prompt that should show the console.log messages from your node.js code. You should be seeing `Response sent` in the command prompt. This won't alert in the page because the page is running on the client side. If you're not seeing the response in the node command prompt/terminal window, you know that it's failing on the server side. Also, I recommend using `response.render()` instead of `res.send()` or others. What is your console messages coming out with on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As adeneo pointed out the key was to serve the html page over
http and not over file protocol. The rest was just some tuning
of various details about the Ajax jQuery call.

**Server-side code:**

```
var mod = require('express');

var auth = require('./acct_module.js');
var fs = require('fs');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());
    
app.post('/login', function(request, response) {
   
   console.log("POST called - try to login against the MongoDB.");
   
   var credentials = request.body;
   console.log("credentials = " + credentials);
   console.log(credentials.username);
   console.log(credentials.password);
   
   auth.authenticate(credentials.username, credentials.password, function(result){
        console.log("Authentication Result: " + result);
        var code = result === 1 ? 200 : 401;
        var message = result === 1 ? "Login succeeded!" : "Login failed!";
        console.log("Response Code: " + code);
        var res = {
            message: message,
            code : code
        };
        
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
        
        response.statusCode = code;
        
        response.json(res);
                    
        console.log("POST response sent.");
   });
   
});

app.get('/login', function(request, response){
    console.log("GET called - send back the HTML file.");
    fs.readFile('login.html', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            response.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.write("Request failed.");
            response.end();
            return;
        }
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.write(data);
        response.end();
        
        console.log("GET response sent.");
    });
});

app.listen(10101);
```

**Login page login.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#btn" ).click(function(){
                  // alert('Now calling the auth manager!');
                  var obj = {
                    username: $('#usrn').val(),
                    password: $('#pwd').val()
                  };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'http://localhost:10101/login',
                    data: obj,
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        // alert('success called!');
                        var res = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
                        $('#status_message').html(res.message);
                        $('#status_code').html(res.code);
                    },
                    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        // alert('error called!');
                        var res = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
                        $('#status_message').html(res.message);
                        $('#status_code').html(res.code);
                    },
                    dataType: 'json'
                });
            })
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="usrn" name="usrn"/><br>
    <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd"/><br>
    <input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="LOGIN!"/><br><br>
    <div id="status_message" name="status_message"></div><br>
    <div id="status_code" name="status_code"></div><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This does what you're looking for: https://github.com/braitsch/node-login

I'd recommend grabbing that from git and looking through it. You could even use it as a template. Pretty good stuff, and when you want to see the client side of things you can just look at the scripts associated with the `login` page.

example here:
http://node-login.braitsch.io/

Comment: I didn't want an existing solution. I am just starting with Node.js and trying to write some code myself. I was able to solve my problem with the help from adeneo (3-4 hours after I posted this question). Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: No problem, sometimes I will look at the code of an existing solution and rewrite my own version. I actually did that with the example I posted. So this was a good guide post for me. Glad you got it worked out!